# Closed app reopens itself after background intent launch

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am writing an application that needs to auto logout after a period of inactivity.

I use a timer to fire a logout event after a period of inactivity.

- After the logout event is fired the user is taken to the login activity.
- The logout event can fire when the app is in the background or the foreground.
- **(added)** The app does not reopen if the user has opened another app. It only reopens when the user is looking at the home screen(s) [desktop]

*Problem:* If the application is in the background the starting of the login activity reopens the application.

### LogoutTimer.java

Responsible for firing 
**`new LogoutEvent()`** after **`AUTO_LOGOUT_WAIT_TIME_MS`**

```
public class LogoutTimer {
    private static LogoutTimer timer;
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable runnable;

    private LogoutTimer() {
        this.handler = new Handler();
        this.runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i(AppConfig.LogTags.SECURITY, "auto logout of application");
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new LogoutEvent(LogoutTypeEnum.SESSION_EXPIRED));
            }
        };
    }

    public static LogoutTimer getInstance() {
        if (timer == null) {
            timer = new LogoutTimer();
        }
        return timer;
    }

    public void restart(String source) {
        Log.i(AppConfig.LogTags.SECURITY, "restarting logout timer. Source: (" + source + ")");
        this.clearHandler();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, AppConfig.AUTO_LOGOUT_WAIT_TIME_MS);
    }

    public void stop(String source) {
        Log.i(AppConfig.LogTags.SECURITY, "stopping logout timer. Source: (" + source + ")");
        this.clearHandler();
    }

    private void clearHandler() {
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }
}
```

### MyApplication.java (the event listener)

The following code starts my LoginActivity. It **also** reopens the application **even** when it is in the background!

The issue also occurs when I put this code inside an Activity.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    // other non relevant code here

    public void onEvent(LogoutEvent event) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(AppConfig.Args.DATA_ITEM_OTHER, event.getLogoutType());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: post your login activity.....when your logout activity closes,, your application doesnt, so it will always reopen it..lol..actualy im now about to read your question..lol

Comment: Its better to use a Background service and that is battery friendly too!

Comment: @Elltz correct. However, I am not sure why the app comes back to the foreground after being backgrounded. I would expect that an app could not reopen itself.

Comment: what do you mean by "reopens the application"?  The application Object is active whenever one of it's activities is running

Comment: The loginActivity comes to the foreground (pops up)

Comment: ive conjured a solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your help with this one @Elltz . What I took from your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25657321/closed-app-reopens-itself-after-background-intent-launch/25696446#25696446) is:

1. I should not fire the `loginActivity` while the application is not active (it seems like this is what was causing the application to come back to the foreground)
2. I can use flags to track whether the application is 'paused' or not

How I did this was as follows:

### BaseActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.application = (MyApplication) getApplication();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.application.activityPaused();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    this.application.activityResumed();
}
```

### MyApplication.java

```
private void startLoginActivity(LogoutTypeEnum logoutType) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(AppConfig.Args.DATA_ITEM_OTHER, logoutType);
    startActivity(intent);
}

public void onEvent(LogoutEvent event) {
    if (this.isActivityPaused) {
        this.shouldLogoutOnResume = true;
        return;
    }

    this.startLoginActivity(event.getLogoutType());
}

public void activityPaused() {
    this.isActivityPaused = true;
}

public void activityResumed() {
    this.isActivityPaused = false;

    if (this.shouldLogoutOnResume) {
        this.startLoginActivity(LogoutTypeEnum.SESSION_EXPIRED);
        this.shouldLogoutOnResume = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ok..this what im thinking.. it auto-logs out then takes you to the loginactivity great -only if user is playing idle on your application ryt??
and the other condition is, if the user is not currently on your app, it shouldnt fire up ryt??

im also conjuring for you creating static custom datas and booleans so you store your conditions, so maybe if the time is due, since your application is up running in background
you can store a

```
boolean logout = true;
```

so the next time users comes back it checks for state and goes on from there..and you can also store your datas too.. to put up some codes let see

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

// other non relevant code here
static boolean activityOnpauseCalled, logOut = false; //put activityOnpauseCalled  = true in your onpause of the main activity

public void onEvent(LogoutEvent event) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(AppConfig.Args.DATA_ITEM_OTHER, event.getLogoutType());
    if(!MyApplication.activityOnpauseCalled){            
       startActivity(intent);
      }
   }
}
```

trigger the logout to true whenever a logout event is fired and activityOnPauseCalled is true. in an if(){} statement and check if logOut is true on onresume of your main Activity

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    MyApplication.activityOnPauseCalled = true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    if(MyApplication.logOut){
       MyApplication.logOut = false;
       //let the user sign in
    }else{
       //do otherwise.. think that would not happen in your case right?? btw,let it start normally
    }
}
```

then finally timertask

```
private LogoutTimer() {
    this.handler = new Handler();
    this.runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.i(AppConfig.LogTags.SECURITY, "auto logout of application");
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new LogoutEvent(LogoutTypeEnum.SESSION_EXPIRED));
            MyApplication.logOut = true;
        }
    };
}
```

hope i am lucid enough..let me know if it was helpful or something else lol..

Comment: Thanks for going to so much effort. This solution looks promising. I'll give it a crack when I am back in the office tomorrow